# Android: how to display the matrix of the image

Tags: android-studio, image-processing

i used this code to get the coordinates xandy of image matrix in android studio
but i cant display these coordinates in textview as example + i wanna to get the average and stander deviation for this matrix

```
@Override
private void logImageViewMatrixInfos(Matrix matrix, ImageView imageView) {
        float[] values = new float[9];
           matrix.getValues(values);
           float globalX = values[2];
           float globalY = values[5];
           float width = values[0]* imageView.getWidth();
           float height = values[4] * imageView.getHeight();

           Log.i("Log value", "Image Details: xPos: " + globalX + " yPos: " + globalY + "\nwidth: " + width + " height: " + height);
    }

    private float getXValueFromMatrix(Matrix matrix) {

        float[] values = new float[9];
           matrix.getValues(values);
           float globalX = values[2];

           return globalX;
    }

    private float getYValueFromMatrix(Matrix matrix) {

        float[] values = new float[9];
           matrix.getValues(values);
           float globalY = values[5];

           return globalY;
    }
```

Comment: Try displaying it as a numpy array

Comment: the code plz to display this array in textview ... thx

Comment: just `print` the array you want to display

Comment: float x = getXValueFromMatrix(matrix);
        textView.setText(x); .... this code is wrong, is this??